# If-else statement is not working, would like to ignoreCase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Everything else on my page works perfectly. The alert(userinput.value); works perfectly... but the statements do not call the button. The code only returns the valid commands in the else statement.

```
      function btn_go_click(){
           var userinput = document.getElementById("txtcommand");   
           alert(userinput.value);         
           if (userinput.value === ("N" || "North")){
              btn_North_click();                
           }else if (userinput.value === ("E" || "East")){ 
              btn_East_click();
           }else if (userinput.value === ("S" || "South")){
              btn_South_click();
           }else if (userinput.value === ("W" || "West")){ 
              btn_West_click();                       
           }else{
            UpdateText ("Valid commands are \"n\", \"e\", \"s\", \"w\"");                   
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 6):

The result of `("N" || "North")` will always be `"N"`.

So `if (userinput.value === ("N" || "North"))` is just same as

`if (userinput.value === "N")`, you need to write:

```
 if (userinput.value === "N" || userinput.value === "North")
```

Or you could write like below (*ignore case*):

```
if (['n', 'north'].indexOf(userinput.value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {

} // ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the case, easiest way is to just have everything on upper case.

```
val valueToCompare = userinput.value.toUpperCase();
```

Then just use all your values on upper case ("NORTH" instead of "North") and you won't even have to care about the user input's casing.

Your ifs are broken. Here's your code fixed:

```
function btn_go_click(){
    var userinput = document.getElementById("txtcommand").value.toUpperCase();   
    alert(userinput.value);         
    if (userinput === "N" || userinput === "NORTH") {
        btn_North_click();                
    } else if (userinput === "E" || userinput === "EAST") {  
        btn_East_click();
    } else if (userinput === "S" || userinput === "SOUTH") {
        btn_South_click();
    } else if (userinput === "W" || userinput === "WEST") { 
        btn_West_click();                       
    } else {
        UpdateText ("Valid commands are \"n\", \"e\", \"s\", \"w\"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore case, you can either convert everything to lower or upper case, or use regular expressions that ignore case, e.g.

```
function btn_go_click(){
    var userinput = document.getElementById("txtcommand");   
    var value = userinput.value.toLowerCase();

    if (value == "n" || value == "north")
```

or

```
    var reN = /^(n|north)$/i;

    if (reN.test(value))
```

You may want to trim leading and trailing spaces from input too so matching is improved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this should be a comment, it it is far too long to make a comment.

If you are making an adventure game, you would be better up making a "command list" rather than trying to make great big if-then.

For instances

```
var cmds = [
  {
    keywords: ["n", "north"],
    help: "Move north, if you can.",
    func: move_north
  },
  {
    keywords: ["get", "take"],
    help: "take an object.",
    func: get_object
  }
];
```

This approach also gives you the built-in commands list and the help files.

In addition, I like having the command parser take a 3-letter short cut so I don't have to type out the entire word.  That is just icing, however.